# pure python ssh

Tags: python, ssh

Are there any implementations of SSH in pure python? Preferably open source?

I'm specifically looking for a client, not server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [paramiko](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko/).

Comment: Is paramiko really pure python?  It seems to require header files in the python-dev (apt) package

Comment: As of 1.12.1, the current release, the published source still is pure Python: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko/1.12.1 .  I'm not sure what package you're looking at.

Answer (score 6):

There is no pure Python library for SSH. [paramiko is not pure python](https://bugs.launchpad.net/paramiko/+bug/402978), because it doesn't work without `pyCrypto` dongle. It may carry a pure Python implementation of SSH protocol, but it is not usable as a pure Python library - you still need to install binary `pyCrypto` extension compiled for your platform, and there is no replacement.